# On Linux, how can I see how far through a file a process is?

Tags: linux, pipe, lsof

If I have a piped command such as

```
   cat myfile | processor_application
```

where processor_application is something reading from standard in, in chunks, to process, is it possible to see how far through the file cat has got?

Possibly using lsof?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the answers so far! However, I should have been clearer: the command is already running.

Comment: Ah yes, then pv is not so handy.  You may want to edit your original question to make that more clear.

Comment: Actually, there are three great separate answers in this question now, so I will leave it as it is.

Comment: Summarising, they are:
1. Use pv (before you start)
2. Use lsof -o (if offsets are supported)
3. look at value of wchar on /proc/<PID>/io , for the known PID of the cat process

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [**pv**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) to do this e.g.

`pv file | processor_application`

As pv passes it's stdin directly to it's stdout you don't need to use cat.

**Edit** 
As your program is already running then find the PID of the `cat` process and then look at the contents of

`/proc/<PID>/io`

which will tell you how many bytes it has written - wchar.

Comment: I only just saw your edit! This works perfectly given the absence of (i) pv in the chain, (ii) lsof -o working. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Absolutely! [Pipe Viewer](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) does exactlty that.  Just insert it in your pipeline:

```
cat myfile | pv | processor_application
```

You can optimize away the `cat` in the above example:

```
pv myfile | processor_application
```

Which has the advantage of providing an actual progress indicator, since pv can determine the size of the input directly.  If you do use pv in the middle of a pipeline, you need to supply the file size yourself to get accurate progress:

```
input_process | pv -s 100M -p | processor_application
```

Check the website for more options to customize pv.

Comment: I like `pv` when it's available :-)

Comment: It is rather easy to insert `pv` into a pipeline by using `mkfifo` and `gdb` (four syscalls with gdb's `p`).

Comment: @grawity you can't tease up like that.  Write up a real answer and demonstrate - I'm very curious now.

Comment: Too much of a hack to be an answer, [but here.](http://purl.net/net/grawity/not-a-blog.html#post:20110131)

Answer (score 6):

If the process is already running lsof has a `size/offset` column which may be helpful to you -- find the PID of the cat process you want to inspect and then `lsof -o -p [PID]`.

If the process is not running yet, `pv` as others suggested is a good option (assuming your system has that utility).

Comment: This is the lsof option that I had looked at. But: what if lsof -o is not allowed or unavailable on the system?

Comment: If `-o` doesn't work on your system I think you're pretty much screwed with respect to using `lsof` :-/  (I assume you're running lsof as the user who launched the `cat` process, or as root?)

Comment: Yes, tried both. I am searching for reasons lsof warns -o as not available now...

Comment: The lsof FAQ, mirrored at http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/utils/admin-tools/lsof/FAQ, implies in point/question 3.43.2.3 that lsof -o is not possible on Linux! I assume this is over-broad, as other users appear to be using lsof -o